# Android - fitsSystemWindows not working with ViewPager.setAdapter

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-statusbar

I have a fragment with structure

```
<CoordinatorLayout
    fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <AppBarLayout
        fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <CollapsingToolbarLayout 
            fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <ImageView
                fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

            <Toolbar />
        </CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout>

        <TabLayout />

        <ViewPager2 /> // with 3 fragments
    </LinearLayout>
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

I want to make ImageView show under the transparent StatusBar. In my Kotlin code, if I call `viewPager.adapter = myAdapter`, it doesn't working.

[image: Picture 1]
[image: Picture 2]

Please help me,

Thanks!